OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory when exporting an .exe from Jupyter Notebook
I am working on a project in Jupyter Notebook and have a notebook named "filename.ipynb" that works successfully. All data is stored locally, and the notebook runs as expected.
To ensure the application runs on external computers without Python installation, I modified the code using current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) for relative file paths (file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, 'data', file_name) instead of local paths. I then exported the notebook using PyInstaller to create a standalone .exe file. The folder structure looks like this:
Project/
- build/
- data/
- dist/
  - filename.exe
- images/
- project_venv/
- filename.py
- filename.spec

The images are loaded correctly from the folder, but I cannot save the data. Instead, it tries to save the data in the following directory, where the "data" folder does not exist:

C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI149362\data

I have ensured that all necessary paths are set correctly and that the folders exist. The problem seems to occur when I attempt to save data to the "data" directory. I am looking for a solution to this issue so that I can successfully run the .exe file on other computers.
Here is the complete error message that occurs:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1968, in __call__
  File "project.py", line 1182, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: [save_design_history_to_file(), save_data('2: Design'), stop_recording(), stop_camera_recording(), show_frame(all_value_frame)])
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "project.py", line 858, in save_design_history_to_file
    df.to_csv(file_path, index=False, sep=';')  
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 333, in wrapper
  File "pandas\core\generic.py", line 3967, in to_csv
  File "pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1014, in to_csv
  File "pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 251, in save
  File "pandas\io\common.py", line 749, in get_handle
  File "pandas\io\common.py", line 616, in check_parent_directory
OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: 'C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI149362\data'

I would appreciate any help or suggestions that could assist me in resolving this issue. Let me know, if you need more information.
